# Creating dojo javascript function with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo

I have a dojo class like this.

```
    var widget = declare("app.util",null, {
        createSecuredLayers: function () {
           $.ajax.get({
                url: "/Api/GetLayer",
                success: function (e) {
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I want to use this object with callback parameters. I mean I want to pass **success** and **error** callbacks as parameter.

```
    var util = new app.util();
    util.createSecuredLayers({
         success:function(){ },
         error:function(){ }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
createSecuredLayers: function(item) {
    $.ajax.get({
        url: "/Api/GetLayer",
        success: item.successCallback,
        error: item.errorCallback
    });
}
```

When you call the method, don't forget to pass the response in the success callback.

```
util.createSecuredLayers({
    successCallback: function(resp) {},
    errorCallback: function(err) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var widget = declare("app.util",null, {
    createSecuredLayers: function (args) {
       $.ajax.get({
            url: "/Api/GetLayer",
            success: args.success,
            error: args.error
        });
    }
});


var util = new app.util();
util.createSecuredLayers({
     success:function(){ },
     error:function(){ }
});
```

You should also consider using Dojo's [deferred](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/deferreds/)